# Html/CSS - Make a single webpage reponsive

Tags: html, css

I woudlike to adapt some div or img in mobile. How can I make it responsive for the mobile format ?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" width="442" height="131" />
                </div>  
            </h1>
            <h1>Enjoy project</h1>
    
        </div>
```

Comment: Use media query with min-width in css, and In images use width: 100% and hight: auto

Comment: "How to make it responsive" is probably too vague a question to be answered.  The design of a page can be achieved many different ways, and the implementation achieved in more ways still.  If you can narrow your question to be more specific, it might be able to be answered here.  Otherwise, I'd recommend just reading the [Responsive Design MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design) for general info on how to make responsive websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some ways to do that, I will add one link at the end that can help, but I will also try to explain it for you.

One of the ways is to adapt your layout using media querys, it works very well but for your case scenario isn't necessary.

So my advice is to work with:

max-height;
min-height;

max-width;
min-width;

Other very important thing is to pay atention on the image proportion, because it can ruin it resolution depending on the device. To solve that problem the better way is through defition of **height** OR **width** as "**auto**".

There isn't much more to say about, the ideal is to test to understand how everything works.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp) you can go to W3Schools documentation that will help you.

Comment: tip : you can add code samples to highlight the codes and make it better to read